# How to use Html.RadioButtonFor in ASP.Net view?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.Net MVC with C# language.
I would like to edit a user. The user table has a boolean field called "IsActive".
In the model, I'm using ADO.Net Entity Data Model.

```
public ActionResult Edit(int id) {
    var editUser = (from u in userEntity.USERs where u.UserId == id select u).First();
    return View(editUser);
}
```

In the view, script generate by Visual Studio for IsActive is using TextBox.

```
<%= Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Activate) %>
```

In this case, I would like to use RadioButton instead with the options Yes and No.
How to do it?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The lambda expressions' body should be the name of the `IsActive` property:

`<%= Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.IsActive) %>`

Also, it seems like you want a `checkbox` and not a `radio`.

Comment: Thanks for you response!
But in here I would like to use Radio button. How?

Comment: When I use this, it displays error: CS0266: Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: Then change it to `model.IsActive.Value` - it is a `Nullable<bool>`. That means that the `IsActive` field in the database allows `null` thus Entity Framework maps that type to a `Nullable<bool>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <%if(Model.Activate){ %> 
    <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Activate, true, new { @id = "radio1", @name = "Activate", @checked="checked" })%>              
    <label for="radio1">Yes</label>
    <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Activate, false, new { @id = "radio2", @name = "Activate" })%> 
    <label for="radio2">No</label>
    <%}else { %>
    <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Activate, true, new { @id = "radio1", @name = "Activate" })%>              
    <label for="radio1">Yes</label>
    <%: Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.Activate, false, new { @id = "radio2", @name = "Activate", @checked = "checked" })%> 
    <label for="radio2">No</label>
<%} %>
```